# Call a function after a certain number of checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fade a div out once a certain amount of check boxes are checked but I can't get it to work. I tried **val** and **length** but I believe I am not pulling the value the correct way for checkboxes?

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked').val > 2) {
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
```

Any input would be greatly appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a selector and check the number of elements found (`length` indicates this).

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var numberChecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (numberChecked > 2) {
        // Fade your div out here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
 $('input:checkbox').change(
function () {
    var checkboxesChecked = 0;
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checkboxesChecked++;
        }
    });

    if (checkboxesChecked > 2) {
        alert('More than 2 checkboxes are checked.');
    }
});
```